# Coinbase Pro Sandbox: How to deposit test money?

Tags: sandbox, coinbase-api

i would like to test the APIs and therefore need money on my sandbox account. How can i deposit fake money for test purposes? this sounds like a quite basic question but i cannot get any information on it:(

Unfortunately the GUI does not provide the possibility. 
I also tried in python but this does not work either. (see https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python)

Has anyone had this issue as well? How can this be solved?

Thank you very much in Advance. Best regards, John

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is the DEPOSIT/WITHDRAW buttons on the UI. You can see the buttons on the right of this [page](https://public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/portfolios) after logging in. In the prompt after clicking DEPOSIT, choose the currency you want the test money in, then choose Coinbase.com as the source.

Comment: This answer doesn't work -- the Deposit button on the sandbox portfolios website only allows me to transfer from another coinbase pro portfolio, and because they're all zero, I can't deposit any fake currency (USD, BTC, or anything else.)

Comment: There is also an option for an "undefined" bank account. Going that route doesn't update the wallet balance immediately. Unclear if the update occurs after 3-5 days to simulate the ACH transaction.

Comment: you have to select the fiat currency linked to your coinbase account. For example If you are trading with EURs, you can only deposit fake euros from coinbase, not fake $ etc.

Comment: The initial deposit of fake funds must be made to the sandbox 'Default' portfolio After that you can move it around.

Comment: Does the sandbox still exist now that pro does not?